# How to limit form values to values with certain numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form which i summitting to a table.
I would like to be able to validate the values before they are 
added to the table.

I would like the a `"time#cnt#"` to be a number that is either a interger 
or a decicimal with only .5.
For example If the user enter a 1.2 and they try to submit it they will get
a error message. They can enter 1 ,1.5 ,.5 ,2.5 ect.

Below is the form that I have , being NEW to JS I have no idea how i would do it.
I have seen on this website and other how i validate if for a number.

```
<cfform method="post" action="time.cfm" >  
 <table >      
    ......
     <td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="time#cnt#" id="add_time" value=""></td>        
    .....

     </table>
    <p><input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value=""></p>
</cfform>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what effort have you made?

Comment: Is [JS Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that will work in all browsers:

```js
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var value = document.getElementById("add_time").value;
    if (!isNumber(value) || (value % 0.5) !== 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Bad input");
        return false;
    }   
}

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" >  
    <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="5" name="time#cnt#" id="add_time" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @StephanMuller of course you are right--I was overthinking it. Updated answer

Comment: is there a reason why it does not work on IE 9? works on firefox and chrome

Comment: @jfishbow This seems to be an issue with the stackoverflow embedded code. It works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm1j2xbd/) in IE9

Comment: @DAVE sorry i meant IE8

Comment: i got it i modify your code a bit ,  if (!isNumber(value) || (value % 0.5) !== 0) {
       
        alert("Bad input");
  return false;
    }

Comment: preventDefault is not supported by IE8

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind sticking to [modern browsers only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation), you can use HTML5's validation. No javascript required. In this case, you want an input of type "number" and set its `step` attribute to "0.5"

```
<input type="number" step=".5" />
```

Now if you put in any number with a decimal that is not .5 the browser will show an error and prevent submitting. Note that older browsers will just treat this as a text input and let everything through, but you should be doing server-side validation anyway. Even a javascript validation can be circumvented.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wtwpz1u9/1/

Comment: this is a great solution , but since browser support,
i need it to work on IE8, it works well with all other
browsers

Answer (score 1):

Try HTML5 validation:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.5" min="1" value="1">
```